# greyscale image normalization issue with MINMAX

Tags: python, arrays, image, opencv, grayscale

I am trying to normalize a bunch of images which I have scaled to 32x32 pixel size. I was initially wanting to use x-median/std for normalization, but I found some code to use MINMAX instead so I am trying that. I need to get the image into the 0 to 1 range, so I assume that dtype 32F would do that, so I think this is where the problem lies. When I run the code, the normalized image is completely black. Any advice on how to solve that?

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


image = cv2.imread("image.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)  # uint8 image
norm_image = np.zeros((32, 32))
norm_image = cv2.normalize(image, norm_image, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type = cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
im = Image.fromarray(norm_image)
if im != 'RGB':
    im = im.convert('RGB')
im.save("image_norm.png")

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSIM5.png)

Comment: Can you attach sample input as well ?

Comment: I have added a sample image. It is a malware binary converted to a greyscale image and then resized to 32x32.

Comment: What's the point of using PIL as well? You already use OpenCV to read and normalize, so why not use it to write the image as well, instead of the shenanigans you're doing. Also, why normalize into floating point, when the next step is to save as PNG? Just stick with uint8 and normalize it to range 0..255

Comment: thank you @DanMašek, your comments helped and I got it working correctly. I appreciate it.